# How do you use a Let's Encrypt certificate with the Alexa service?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, alexa-skills-kit

I created a Let's Encrypt certificate using SSLforFREE. It works great in the browser, but generates an "unknown certificate" error when used with an Alexa skill. Manually uploading the certificate to the Alexa service works, but it will not work as a "trusted" certificate.

Has anyone successfully used one of these as a "trusted" certificate with Alexa?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, here's what you can do:

1. Download the contents of your fullchain.pem cert, from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem` on your server
2. On your skill config page, select the "SSL" Tab.
3. Mark "I will upload a self-signed certificate in X.509 format."
4. Paste the contents of your fullchain.pem file.

It worked for me. Not sure if chain or cert would be enough.

Comment: Are you sure this works? What if the certificate is renewed?

Comment: This worked for me. I did use sslforfree first which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Dont use sslforfree. Use Letsencrypt fullchain certificates directly**

Though certificates from https://www.sslforfree.com/ utilizes [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate chain, amazon finds an [issue](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/3097/any-luck-with-lets-encrypt.html) while tracing to a trusted certificate authority.

This is [another discussion](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/76425/alexa-service-rejects-our-access-token-uri-certifi.html) on missing certificate chains.

The solution that will work is, **Use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates directly** with chained certificates to a trusted CA certificate.

For this, use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) in order to generate LetsEncrypt certificate on your Server and follow the steps in @aldrinleal answer.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by that "issue" that Amazon "finds"? Additionally, if you want to back the answer by aldrinleal, you should upvote it and not post an additional answer that does not solve the question

Comment: Not sure the reason why answer is voted down. I have updated the answer with link to a discussion about missing chains.

Comment: Note that this will only working in testing *not* production. It seems that Amazon has explicity decided [not to trust](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/208096/audio-hosted-on-own-https-endpoint-ssl-certificate.html) Let's Encrypt certificates in production even though they are not self signed.