# Amazon Alexa Custom Skill using letsencrypt SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, alexa-skills-kit, lets-encrypt

I am trying to publish my Alexa skill using Letsencrypt SSL Certificate.
Google Chrome does not show any warning icon if I browse to my https URL using letsencrypt certificate.

However, when I try to test using Alexa console, an error occurs as :
"SSL Handshake failed".

I see on Amazon Alexa forums that there is a buzz around letsencrypt support.
Some posts say it is supported and some say it isn't.

Could someone here clarify whether letsencrypt free SSL certificate is supported for building **custom alexa skills** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the contents of your fullchain.pem cert, from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem` on your server
2. On your skill config page, select the "SSL" Tab.
3. Mark "I will upload a self-signed certificate in X.509 format."
4. Paste the contents of your fullchain.pem file.

Comment: And this solution has amazingly worked but with little tweak. I didn't see SSL config in my skill config. So, I took the fullchain.pem generated by letsencrypt and created a .p12 type certificate using openssl. Now amazon didn't find any ssl handshake issue. Thanks.

Comment: Attribution should be given to the answer previously given to question [How do you use a Let's Encrypt certificate with the Alexa service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149711)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate working with an Alexa custom skill after choosing the option "*My development endpoint is a sub-domain of a domain that has a wildcard certificate from a certificate authority*" in the developer console.

I also had an issue with a Nginx reverse proxy configuration that caused a failure in the Alexa Simulator and provided no helpful error.  Fortunately you can also use the Manual JSON option which yielded the error "*Cannot establish SSL connection to your skill endpoint*".

I was able to track the issue down to the `ssl_ciphers` value in the ssl.conf file.  Even though it was compatible with the [Intermediate Security](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Intermediate_compatibility_.28recommended.29) recommended setting for TLS 1.2, I had to comment it out to make it work.  I hope someone else can determine why Amazon servers reject the certificate when this setting is used, it could be that TLS 1.3 is now required.